# Using C# Linq find and return a string value from a multi-level data store

Tags: c#, linq

I have a custom config stored in memory `DomainConfigElements`.

```
  <RemoteAppConfiguration>
    <domains>
      <domain name="abc" isenabled="true">
        <remoteapps>
          <remoteapp name="app1" applicationname="app1shortcut" isenabled="true" />
          <remoteapp name="app2" applicationname="app2shortcut" isenabled="true" />
        </remoteapps>
      </domain>
      <domain name="efg" isenabled="false">
        <remoteapps>
          <remoteapp name="app3" applicationname="app3exe" isenabled="true" />
          <remoteapp name="app4" applicationname="app4exe" isenabled="true" />
        </remoteapps>        
      </domain>
      <domain name="xyz" isenabled="true">
        <remoteapps>
          <remoteapp name="app5" applicationname="app5launcher" isenabled="true" />
          <remoteapp name="app6" applicationname="app6launcher" isenabled="true" />
        </remoteapps>        
      </domain>
    </domains>    
  </RemoteAppConfiguration>
```

I have to find an app `app5` and return the `applicationanme`. In this example, I have to return a string `app5launcher`. If I pass `app2` then the code should return `app2shortcut`.

I wanted to use `linq` to get the desired result. This is what I came with:

```
var fixedParam = "app6";
var apps = AppUtilities.DomainConfigElements.Where(d => d.IsEnabled)
         .Select(d => d.RemoteApps
         .Where(r => string.Equals(r.Name, fixedParam, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))).FirstOrDefault();
var appName = apps.Select(a => a.ApplicationName).FirstOrDefault();
```

It gets me the result, but looks complex. I feel this can be simplified. I wanted to know is there a better way of doing this? I tried to ask this question in `codereview.stackexchange` but the website seems to be not working right now.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer:

The original LINQ query you posted is picking a list of `RemoteApp` that match the criteria `Name` to `fixedParam`. The final `.FirstOrDefault()` query in the first LINQ statement picks first item from that list and stores in `apps`.

2nd LINQ query `apps.Select(a => a.ApplicationName).FirstOrDefault();` just picks `ApplicationName` attribute from `apps`, which should only be one item anyway. Then, `FirstOrDefault()` is called again.

The main reason this is inefficient is because of redundant `FirstOrDefault()` calls. However, it does handle case where multiple `RemoteApp` items have same `Name` attribute.

My solution starts by picking enabled `Domain` object from `DomainConfigElements`. There is an additional query in here that ensures the `Domain` being picked **also** contains the `RemoteApp` object with `Name == FixedParam`. Once the correct `Domain` is selected, I query on `RemoteApps` in the domain and pick `RemoteApp` that matches `Name == fixedParam`. Then, we just get `ApplicationName` property.

```
AppUtilities.DomainConfigElements
                .Where(d => d.IsEnabled) // get enabled domains
                .Select(d => d.RemoteApps // query on remote apps inside domain
                    .FirstOrDefault(app => app.Name == "app2")) 
                .FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name == "app2").ApplicationName; // query on fixedParam
```

I mocked up your class structure in my own IDE to get the statements correct, but I have not run it against your XML yet. Let me know if this works for you, otherwise I will remove :)

Comment: `.FirstOrDefault(domain => domain.RemoteApps` line gives an error `Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type`.  And `IsEnabled` can be critical, depending on other `domain` in he config that are disabled for now. I will add it to my example.

Comment: That makes sense. Let me try to write my own class-mockup of your example and see if I can test in my IDE.

Comment: @SriReddy seeing the same error message as you. working on it.

Comment: @SriReddy I've updated my LINQ query to no longer throw an error message -- let me know if this works for you. Otherwise, I will let someone else take a crack at this :)

Comment: I did a quick test, it worked. Let me test thoroughly and get back to you.

Comment: Somehow it only works with the first remoteapp `app1`. The last query `.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name == "app1").ApplicationName;` throws an exception as the query before returns null.

Comment: That's interesting. I believe this query, based somewhat on the initial example you provided, may work: `var apps = AppUtilities.DomainConfigElements.Where(d => d.IsEnabled)
         .Select(d => d.RemoteApps
         .Where(r => string.Equals(r.Name, fixedParam, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))).ApplicationName;`